# Network monitoring using Sysmon don't monitor all events

Tags: networking, monitoring

I'm using Sysmon for network monitoring, but instead of monitoring all of my requested destinations, it monitors just specific ones, while the rest of them stay unmonitored. 
I'll explain - 
    In order to monitor google and github visits, I wrote the next config:

```
<Sysmon schemaversion="4.21">
<HashAlgorithms>*</HashAlgorithms>
<CheckRevocation/>
<EventFiltering>
    <RuleGroup name="" groupRelation="or"><NetworkConnect onmatch="include">
        <DestinationHostname condition="contains">google.com</DestinationHostname>
        <DestinationHostname condition="contains">.github.com</DestinationHostname>
    </NetworkConnect></RuleGroup>
    <RuleGroup name="" groupRelation="or"><DnsQuery onmatch="include"></DnsQuery></RuleGroup>
    <RuleGroup name="" groupRelation="or"><ProcessCreate onmatch="include"></ProcessCreate></RuleGroup>
    <RuleGroup name="" groupRelation="or"><FileCreateTime onmatch="include"></FileCreateTime></RuleGroup>
    <RuleGroup name="" groupRelation="or"><ProcessTerminate onmatch="include"></ProcessTerminate></RuleGroup>
    <RuleGroup name="" groupRelation="or"><DriverLoad onmatch="include"></DriverLoad></RuleGroup>
    <RuleGroup name="" groupRelation="or"><ImageLoad onmatch="include"></ImageLoad></RuleGroup>
    <RuleGroup name="" groupRelation="or"><CreateRemoteThread onmatch="include"></CreateRemoteThread></RuleGroup>
    <RuleGroup name="" groupRelation="or"><RawAccessRead onmatch="include"></RawAccessRead></RuleGroup>
    <RuleGroup name="" groupRelation="or"><ProcessAccess onmatch="include"></ProcessAccess></RuleGroup>
    <RuleGroup name="" groupRelation="or"><FileCreate onmatch="include"></FileCreate></RuleGroup>
    <RuleGroup name="" groupRelation="or"><RegistryEvent onmatch="include"></RegistryEvent></RuleGroup>
    <RuleGroup name="" groupRelation="or"><FileCreateStreamHash onmatch="include"></FileCreateStreamHash></RuleGroup>
    <RuleGroup name="" groupRelation="or"><PipeEvent onmatch="include"></PipeEvent></RuleGroup>
    <RuleGroup name="" groupRelation="or"><WmiEvent onmatch="include"></WmiEvent></RuleGroup>
</EventFiltering>
```

and ran it with

```
sysmon -i C:\temp\sysmon\config.xml -accepteula
```

Next, I'v entered to google.com and github.com, and checked my Event Viewr for result. The only result that cought by Sysmon was from github.com, but no activity from google.com were log to the Event Log (And this is always the situation, it agree to monitor github but won't monitor google)

What am I missing? Why can't I monitor any website and is there a way around it?

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: I don't know sysmon, but three (quite possibly irrelevant) questions come to mind: **(a)** why `google.com` (no leading `.`) but `.github.com` (with a leading `.`)? Would `.google.com` be different? **(b)** Might you be accessing Github over HTTP but Google over HTTPS? and **(c)** Are you accessing both through the same thing (e.g. the same browser), or might you be accessing Github through, for example, Git client software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently Google has a lot of hostnames for connections to www.google.com, so the hostname probably won't have "google" in it.
The solution -  monitor hostnames using Sysmon's DNSQuery (Event ID 22).
The problem with the solution - Not working on Windows 7.